# web crawler blocked/blacklisted

Tags: ubuntu, web-crawler, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm wrote a web crawler and ran it on a Ubuntu virtual machine (VirtualBox), which is hosted on a Window machine. The crawler got blocked/blacklisted by the site I tried to crawl (got the Access Denied page), presumably because I hit it too hard.

However, my Window machine is still able to open the website, so is my other other Ubuntu virtual machine running on a different computer.

**All virtual machines and actual computers live in the same WIFI environment**. So I'd guess the virtual machine got blacklisted by its local IP address, or some other identities. So I tried the following things

1. Used a different (static) ip address
2. Changed the MAC address from Virtual Box to a differnt one
3. Added and used a new network adapter with differnt ip address from Virtual Box
4. Installed new Ubuntu virtual machines (same and different version) on VirtualBox and tried to access the site

None of these works.
Any idea how to change the identity of the Ubuntu virtual machine?

**edit: I used Selenium/chromedrive to crawl. All requests were indeed sent from actual browser.**

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to useragent that you are sending with request is bad. Are you using fake-useragent? They might be blocking those who gives request that has indication of bot/human.
E.g. in Python you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent to send fake-useragent together with request.

Comment: I tried to use different browsers and 'curl' command to fetch the same page. The user-agents should be different, but still got blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a 401 Access Denied HTTP response when you use your crawler, but your browser's requests are successful, then best option is to do a full comparison of the two HTTP requests using an interception proxy like Burp Suite (Link below).

Configure your browser and your web crawler to send their requests to Burp - then burp will forward them to the site. You can then view, compare and manipulate the requests.

Keep intercepting your web crawler requests, each time changing them to be more like your browser request - eventually the request will work and you'll know what you need to change in your crawler.

[Burp Suite Community Edition](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload)

Answer (score -2):

Your IP is blocked, if you use a different internet service provider you may be still able to crawl for a while until they detect it again.

You can always find your public IP:

https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: No... my other devices under the same WIFI evironment can still access the site. They should have the same public IP. 

Just double checked with whatismyip.com, all machines have the same public IP.